# How to custom code in Laravel-5 from PHP

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I want to transform this code for laravel blade template `<?php echo ($page=="menu" ? "header-active" : "")?>`

i have code in Php to make header menu.

```
<ul class = "menu-container">
        <li class="header-hover <?php echo ($page=="home" ? "header-active" : "")?>">
            <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}"><div class="menu">HOME</div></a>            </li>
        <li class="header-hover <?php echo ($page=="menu2" ? "header-active" : "")?>">
            <div class="menu">Menu 2</div>
            <ul class="in">
                <li><a href="{{URL::to('/menu2 A')}}">MENU 2A</div></a>            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Please Help me I get error : *Undefined variable: page*

Comment: This code should work. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for? Do you want to transform this code for laravel blade template? (Although this one should work)

Comment: Where does that variable "$page" first appear? Where does it get populated with "home" or "menu2"?

Comment: I'm guessing that `$page` is a variable that should have been supplied by the controller? But I can't tell just from seeing the view. What does your controller code look like? In particular, the code where you call `View::make()` (or whatever other method you use to display the view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following -
`{!!$page=="layanan" ? "header-active" : ""!!}`.

Before that, make sure you have installed `laravelcollective/html`

If not, Follow the below steps,

1. add `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` in the require feild inside composer.json file in the root of the project.
2. Run `composer update` from root of your project. This will install the package required for **blade templating** by laravel.
3. In config/app.php, under `providers` add    `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class`.
4. In config/app.php, under `aliases`  add `'Form'=>Collective\Html\FormFacade::class` and
      `'Html'=>Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class`.

Thankyou :)